# How can I pass a variable from a class to another class, which is in a different file?

Tags: flutter

I am very new to flutter and app development in general. It is my first project where I encountered a problem that I cannot solve.
The app has a home page, where there are 4 buttons. One of the buttons('settings') leads to an alert dialog, where the user can input settings(7 different textfields for 7 different settings), mostly related to time, as the app has to control times(that is the purpose of the app).
On another page('tournament page'), I need to have access to these controllers(TextEditingController), since there will be calculations based on the settings, which the user put in beforehand.
How could I pass the data, or how do I have access to these 7 settings(controllers) from the other page, which is of course in another class, and also not in the same file?
Unfortunately, I've been stuck on this problem for awhile now, and I can't manage to solve it on my own. Any solution, idea or tips in general on how I can improve in the future is highly appreciated. And also, how does my code look?- how can I improve it? Thanks a lot!!
My code:

```
class SettingsAlertDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsAlertDialog({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // inputs --> the controllers of the settings menu

    const List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
      controllers.add(TextEditingController());
    } 
    /* i used a for loop to generate 7 TextEditingController and put it in 
    a list, and it correlates with the 7 settings input */

    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text(
        'Time Control',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          // header of settings

          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 30,
                child: Text('Per.'),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 50,
                child: Text('Time'),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 50,
                child: Text('Bonus'),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 50,
                child: Text('Move'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),

          // first period

          SettingsRow(
            periodText: '1.',
            timeController: controllers[0],
            bonusController: controllers[1],
            moveController: controllers[2],
            // SettingRow is a class I made  , there are more of these, but you get the point
          ),
```

to save your time, I publish only the important parts of the program
this is the other page

```
class TournamentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TournamentPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TournamentPage> createState() {
    return _TournamentPageState();
  }
}

class _TournamentPageState extends State<TournamentPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> tournamentTables = [];
for (int i = 1; i <= **12**; i++) {
      tournamentTables.add(i);
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Tournament',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
```

For example: I want to change the hard coded 12 to one of the TextEditingController from the list I made in the other class/in the other file(the code above).

I've tried many things, none of which worked.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

here when you use the widget TournamentPage in another widget you will have to pass a lost of textEditingControllers from that page to this one and this should bring here what you need

```
class TournamentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TournamentPage({super.key, required this.controllers});

final List<TextEditingController> controllers ;

  @override
  State<TournamentPage> createState() {
    return _TournamentPageState();
  }
}

class _TournamentPageState extends State<TournamentPage> {

//this is how you can access the value you pass to a stateful widget and you //shoud print it to see you got the list. now you can use it to display what //you want in this widget

print(widget.controllers);

//your code
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> tournamentTables = [];
//etc
}
```

i hope i understood right what you need and i helped you, is the first time i try to help someone on stackoverflow

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you are saying is that I should pass in the list when making TournamentPage, something like  'TournamentPage(controllers: controllers)'. But how can I pass the controllers, which i made in the tournament_page file to the home page? (home page is where I made routes and the tournamentpage takes the arguaments, and it is in the main.dart file).

Comment: Pass them from home to tournament_page and then from tournament_page to the page you need them. There is also a very good solution for keeping some data that could be accessed from every file. it is something called riverpood or bloc. this is very useful if the data changes in one page and you want it to be changed everywhere. i personally use bloc cubit and there are tutorials online that will help you with it. Once you understand this cubit bloc tool it will be very useful

Comment: And if I make routes in the main.dart, and make the list in the home_page.dart, then how do I pass the list to the tournament in the routes? Is not making routes the solution? And is it bad if I declare variables, such as lists in the build block of the main.dart file?(if I don't want the list to get to the default list of TextEditingController whenever homepage is called? Also, could you recommend a good tutorial? You've helped me a lot so far! Thankss!!!

Comment: check this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y564ETOCog8
Search and learn online about cubit and bloc. i have some suggestions for after you finish the video and start using this. this is what i use. for each page in general i have 3 files for each page i have in the project and i use AutoRouter package to create the navigations between pages. the files are x_page.dart, x_states.dart and x_cubit.dart. In the page i try to have only the UI, in cubit i define the methods and i use them inthe page. in general each method from the cubit declares a state after it is executed

Comment: i then listen to the changes into the ui automatically with the help of bloc and the ui is updated accordingly

Comment: I'll definitely look into state management then. But for this project, I think I'll stick with only flutter since I am a very beginner and it might be too much for me at the moment. For the future, is there any way I could contact you if I face a problem? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I searched and i don't think there is a way to send a message here, we could comment an email or something and after the other one sends an email we could delete the comments with our contact info from here:))

Comment: I sent you an email :)